# Override properties in pom.xml

Tags: maven

I am trying to override the properties in pom.xml.
The properties sections says
    
    **/MyTest.java

```
<execution>
<id>run-stories-as-embeddables</id>
<phase>integration-test</phase>
<configuration>
<scope>test</scope>
<includes>
<include>${pathExpression}</include>
</includes>
```

I want the property to be overriden if sent externally while running pom.xml goal else a default value should be picked up.

Can you please advise?

Thanks,
Rakesh

Comment: Use [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). You can choose which value to acquire depending on the profile.

Comment: if you are using the failssafe plugin here you probably need to make some profiles. the includes config has no user property to be set on the command line: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Can I pass it as an jvm argument using -D?? Well the property is not overriden and it takes the value specified in the pom.xml file?

Comment: You can override a Maven property with the command line. Just set a default value in your POM (<properties><myProp>foo</myProp></properties>) and override it when needed with a -DmyProp=bar